# Getting linearized indices in numpy

Tags: matlab, numpy

I need to emulate the MATLAB function `find`, which returns the linear indices for the nonzero elements of an array. For example:

```
>> a = zeros(4,4)
a =

     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
>> a(1,1) = 1
>> a(4,4) = 1
>> find(a)
ans =

     1
    16
```

numpy has the similar function `nonzero`, but it returns a tuple of index arrays. For example:

```
In [1]: from numpy import *
In [2]: a = zeros((4,4))

In [3]: a[0,0] = 1

In [4]: a[3,3] = 1

In [5]: a
Out[5]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])

In [6]: nonzero(a)
Out[6]: (array([0, 3]), array([0, 3]))
```

Is there a function that gives me the linear indices without calculating them myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

numpy has you covered:

```
>>> np.flatnonzero(a)
array([ 0, 15])
```

Internally it's doing exactly what Sven Marnach suggested.

```
>>> print inspect.getsource(np.flatnonzero)
def flatnonzero(a):
    """
    Return indices that are non-zero in the flattened version of a.

    This is equivalent to a.ravel().nonzero()[0].

    [more documentation]

    """
    return a.ravel().nonzero()[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is to flatten the array before calling `nonzero()`:

```
>>> a.ravel().nonzero()
(array([ 0, 15]),)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `matplotlib` installed it's probably already there (`find` that is) in `matplotlib.mlab` module, as well as some other functions intended for compatibility with matlab. And yes it's implemented the same way as `flatnonzero`.